# AVAudio Recorder is not recording after comes from background

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have used **AVAudioRecorder**. The recorder is not recording when i come from **background**.

My Scenario is

1. Start recording press home button (Recording stopped)
2. Open my app the recorder is still recording (Checked by recorder.isRecording is YES)
3. Stop the recording and playing the recorded audio plays only what recorded before my app goes background.
4. I am recoding 5sec -> app goes background -> comes fore foreground -> record another 5 secs -> play the audio the audio plays only the first 5 secs.

**While recording I am checking the size of the file path given to the audio recorder(By NSTimer) the file size is not increased after come from background but still the recorder status is recording**

Can any one point out what is the mistake. Thanks

**Note: in ios6 there is no problem it plays entire audio that is entire 10 sec it comes only in ios7**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you dont want to record in the background and you only want to append your recording before and after going to background, pause your recorder in `applicationWillEnterBackground` (or `applicationWillResignAcive`) and when you come back form background, continue your recording and you'd be fine. (You can have notifications letting your class which is recording know about those life cycle delegate methods.)
But if you want to record in the background you need to turn on Background Mode: Audio and Airplay in your app settings -> Capabilities. But thats another story.

Comment: You answered what I did. I solved the issue by that only. Any way i ll accept the answer. It ll help others

Answer (score 0):

You should check `AVAudioSessionDelegate` delegate method. Audio recording will stop during phone call

```
- (void)beginInterruption{

}
-(void)endInterruption{
}
```

You can continue background recording. Add the background modes as seen in image

[image]

Comment: No there is no phone call. It happens when i goes back ground. next thing it is working well in ios6

Comment: have you checked audioRecorder.recording what it returns? on the foreground state

Comment: [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err]; have to set this

Comment: yeah I hv done all those things correctly. The problem is the recorder doesn't append the recording after comes from background this is the problem

Comment: i think the problem with ur code at anywhere. because in my app its working fine.

Comment: if problem in my code means how it is working in ios6. That's is confused me.